# How to make Altrium pan-scroll with mouse wheel?

Tags: altium

I'm on the verge switching E-CAD from Proteus to Altium, so I'm trying out the evaulation version to see if we match.

One thing that I cannot cope with is the actions bound to the mouse wheel. In Proteus, I pan the view using mouse click (hold it to drag the views), while in Altium it seems to be bound to some sort of zoom.

Heading to Preferences->Mouse Wheel, I managed to get rid of the horizontal / vertical scroll using the wheel (I use it to zoom in/out instead, like in Proteus) but I cannot seem to understand how to make the pan scroll-behaviour like I want, since the fourth column is grayed out.

How can I make Altrium to pan-drag the view when the mouse wheel is pressed?

[image]

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks, I can live with that. Please make your comment an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to do it, but by default this is mapped to click-drag on the right mouse button. You don't have to modify your behavior much to adapt to the Altium default, fortunately.